# How do i make an molecular orbital diagram step by step?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

My professor explained me, but i'm still unable to do a correct molecular orbital, for a diatomic molecule

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50279/how-should-i-construct-the-orbitals-of-dilithium-using-only-pen-and-paper

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/energetic-placement-of-atomic-orbitals-in-the-hcl-molecular-orbital-diagram