# Intuition for the overlap integral

Tags: physical-chemistry

I want to ask a question about the overlap integral.

I was studying about the MO diagram of $\ce{H_2^+}$ and we managed to derive an expression which had the following term:

$$\langle \mathrm{1s}_\ce{A}(r_\ce{A}) | \mathrm{1s}_\ce{B}(r_\ce{B}) \rangle$$

and our lecturer later explained that this is known as the **overlap integral**.

> The overlap integral is the magnitude to which the atoms overlap when combining AOs to produce MOs.

The trouble is, I later wanted to find a proof for this idea in order to confirm my understanding of this idea, but could not find anything that could explain this phenomenon from principle.

I did come across [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60601/what-are-overlap-integrals), but this only explained its main definition and not actually any derivation from basic principle.

How can the overlap integral be explained from basic principle?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. The overlap integral is just *defined* to be that integral (or even more simply, that integral is *given* the name of "overlap"); there's no "derivation" involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Phi, \Psi$ be normalized wave functions.

Then $0 \le|\langle\Phi\vert\Psi\rangle| \le 1$, with $\langle\Phi\vert\Phi\rangle = 1$ and $\langle\Phi\vert\Psi\rangle = 0$ for orthogonal $\Phi$ and $\Psi$.

Since we can argue that any wave function completely contains itself and for two orthogonal wave functions none of them contains a part of the other, we can interpret the scalar product $\langle\Phi\vert\Psi\rangle$ as a measure for overlap.